# how do i call a method from a wsdl

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

i am trying to call a method from a wsdl and getting an error. i am new to soap and learning all i can. i know rest is better but i really want to learn soap. this is what i have so far:

```
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enable', '0');
$client = new SoapClient('http://ws.cdyne.com/delayedstockquote/delayedstockquote.asmx?wsdl');
$data = $client->__soapCall('GetQuote', array('GetQuote' => 'aapl'));
print $data;
```

the error i get is

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. in /Volumes/www/public/soap/s.php:5 Stack trace: #0 /Volumes/www/public/soap/s.php(5): SoapClient->__soapCall('GetQuote', Array) #1 {main} thrown in /Volumes/www/public/soap/s.php on line 5
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see all required parameters for the `GetQuote` request in `http://ws.cdyne.com/delayedstockquote/delayedstockquote.asmx?wsdl`

You should pass a `StockSymbol` and `LicenseKey`. Example of request:

```
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enable', '0');
$client = new SoapClient('http://ws.cdyne.com/delayedstockquote/delayedstockquote.asmx?wsdl');
$data = $client->GetQuote(array('StockSymbol' => 'TEST_STR','LicenseKey' => 'TEST_STR'));
print_r($data);
```

Replace TEST_STR with your data